How add 'install website as app' function on my website
i want to add download button on my website where users will be able to download my website and use it as app. i have found that button on some websites for example freelancer.com has it and its possible to download freelancer and use it as app.
here is image


i found answer on youtube for nextjs14 App router
youtube link
